# DropboxSDK: unable to link

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I keep on getting dropbox error, : [ERROR] DropboxSDK: unable to link; app isn't registered for correct URL scheme. I believe I have done everything correctly. I have researched online and the most common cause is the info.plist but i don't think I have that error. Am I making a mistake?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your URL scheme should be `db-v6jhkrthdgi5z0s`. Note the `db-` prefix to your Dropbox id.